# Export user alert list

Tags: alert, user

SP2013, I would like to be able to export a list of everyone who has set an alert on a specific list or library.  I can see how to edit specific user's alerts, but I'd like to have the full list of users exported.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static string listarAlertasLista(SPWeb web, string listaInternalName)
{
    string alerts = "";
    string listUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/" + listaInternalName;
    listUrl = listUrl.Replace("//", "/");

    SPList list = web.GetList(listUrl);
    SPAlertCollection alertsColl = web.Alerts;

    alerts += "<span style='color: blue'>Alertas de la lista " + listaInternalName + "</span><br>";
    foreach (SPAlert alert in alertsColl)
    {
        if (alert.ListID == list.ID)
        {
            alerts += "Usuario: " + alert.User.LoginName + "<br>";
            alerts += "Tipo: " + alert.AlertType + "<br>";
            alerts += "Canales: " + alert.DeliveryChannels.ToString() + "<br>";
        }
    }

    return alerts;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP asked for all user alerts on a list, not all alerts for a single user.

Comment: Paul is correct-this answer is not what I needed.  It's pretty easy to manage the alert set by a single user using the Site Settings-User Alerts.  But I need to know the names of about 800-1000 people that were supposed set an alert on a specific list.  I'm using the alert feature as a required communication, thus I need to know who the alert is being sent to.

Comment: I modified my answer based on the comments. Hope this can help you. If you need help tell me